# React Native Passing Parameter to Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a tab navigator and I was wondering if I can pass a parameter to the tab navigator and use that parameter in the HomePage component.

I am passing the parameter from a Drawer Navigator using `this.props.navigation.navigate('TabsNav', {testParam: 'TEST'})`.

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a navigator like this?

**TabNav.js**

```
export const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    HomePage: {
      screen: Home,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel:"Home Page",
      },
    },
    ListView: {
      screen: List,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel:"List View",
      }
    },
  },

  {
    order: ['HomePage', 'ListView'],
  },
)
```

**DrawerContainer.js**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.TouchableHighlight}
            onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('TabsNav', {testParam: 'TEST'})}

            <Text>Home</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

        <View>
          <TouchableHighlight
            style={styles.TouchableHighlight}
            onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfilePage')}>

            <Text>List View</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>


      </View>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to navigate to a screen specifically inside of the tab, not to the tab itself, or the params go into the tab navigator. params only go to the route that you are navigating to directly.

so

```
Drawer({
  TabsNav: Tab({
    HomePage: ScreenA,
    ListView: ScreenB,  
  })
});
```

navigate to HomePage or ListView rather than TabsNav